# If exists in table 1 display table 2 else display table 1 for table 3 records in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm trying to display distinct record from my table, but doesn't work.

Here I have ALL_RECORD table

```
ID    NAME    STUD_ID    INFO
 1     Jose    123456    abcd
 1     Jose    <null>    abcd
 2     Ann     123457    abcde
 2     Ann     <null>    abcde
 3     Kyle    123444    abcdq
 4     Cynt    <null>    abcdw
 4     Cynt    111112    abcdw
```

My ALL_RECORD table values were inserted from my RECORD1 and RECORD2

RECORD1 Table

```
ID    NAME    STUD_ID    INFO
 1     Jose    <null>    abcd
 2     Ann     <null>    abcde
 4     Cynt    <null>    abcdw
```

RECORD2 Table

```
ID    NAME    STUD_ID    INFO
 1     Jose    123456    abcd
 2     Ann     123457    abcde
 3     Kyle    123444    abcdq
 4     Cynt    111112    abcd
```

What I want to display

```
ID    NAME    STUD_ID    INFO
 1     Jose    <null>    abcd
 2     Ann     <null>    abcde
 3     Kyle    123444    abcdq
 4     Cynt    <null>    abcdw
```

Please notice id no. 3.

My test query1

```
select distinct(id), name, stud_id, info from ALL_RECORD;
```

My test query2

```
select * from ALL_RECORD where id is null;
```

My test query3

```
select * from ALL_RECORD where id is null and id in (select * from record2) group by id;
```

still can't get the correct output

Comment: Unrelated, but: `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to **all** columns in the select list. `distinct  (id), name` is _exactly_ the same thing as `distinct id,name` or `distinct id,(name)`

Comment: "If exists in table 1 display table 2 else display table 1"? So if a record does *not* exist in table 1 we shall show that non-existing record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a window function:

```
select id, name, stud_id, info
from (
   select id, name,stud_id,info, 
          row_number() over (partition by id,name order by stud_id nulls first) as rn
   from all_record
) t
where rn = 1;
```

The row_number() assigns sequential numbers based on the sort criteria specified with the `order by` clause. As you want the `null` values to have a higher "priority" then a not-null value you need to use `nulls first` to give them the row number 1. Note that if there is more then one row for the combination `id,name` with a null value for `stud_id` this picks an arbitrary one.

Comment: It works, tho, I'm not familiar with window function. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to show all table2 records plus those table1 records where the ID cannot be found in table2.

```
select id, name, stud_id, info from table2
union all
select id, name, stud_id, info from table1 where id not in (select id from table2)
order by id;
```

Comment: but only the table ALL_RECORD exists

Comment: Then it's surprising you were able to write your query #3.

Comment: So the request title is wrong, the two original tables don't exist anymore (which you forgot to tell us) and you are showing a query that can't possibly work because the table doesn't exist (which you should have known, but you didn't even bother to tell us that the query does not run). Next time please don't give such incoherent information in order not to waste our time again.